# xml using with bulleted list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, bulletedlist

I am trying to create a bulleted list and use an xml file (`Kategoriler.xml`) as data source. Here is my `xml` code:

```
<bookstore>
 <book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

And design of page:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList2" runat="server" BulletStyle="Numbered" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
</asp:BulletedList>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/Kategoriler.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

When I run the code i see a list like this:

```
1.System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSourceNodeDescriptor
2.System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSourceNodeDescriptor
3.System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSourceNodeDescriptor
4.System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSourceNodeDescriptor
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the `DataTextField` & `DataValueField` properties in your `BulletedList`:-

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList2" runat="server" BulletStyle="Numbered" 
     DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" DataTextField="author" DataValueField="year" >
</asp:BulletedList>
```

**Update:**

@Michael is correct `XmlDataSource` does not work with values of xml nodes but only with attributes, so either you will have to modify your XML like this:-

```
<bookstore>
 <book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author name="Giada De Laurentiis" year="2005"></author>
  <year></year>
  <price>30.00</price>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

Then, you will have to specify the `XPath` attribute like this:-

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/Kategoriler.xml" 
  XPath="/bookstore/book/author"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Then, change your BulletedList attributes accordingly:-

```
DataTextField="name" DataValueField="year"
```

But, in reality you probably won't be able to change your XML itself so you can read this XML in code behind and then programmatically bind your BulletedList.

**Update 2:**

As I said it's not practical to change your XML file according to the `XMLDataSource` behavior you can alternatively use `LINQ-to-XML` to query your XML file and bind it like this:-

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"YourXMLFilePath");
var XMLdata = xdoc.Descendants("book")
                   //Optional Filter
                   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("category") == "cooking") 
                   .Select(x => new
                           {
                              AuthorName = (string)x.Element("author"),
                              Year = (string)x.Element("year")
                           });
```

Finally, you can bind the data like this:-

```
BulletedList2.DataSource = XMLdata;
BulletedList2.DataValueField = "Year";
BulletedList2.DataTextField = "AuthorName";
BulletedList2.DataBind();
```

Comment: This [won't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290515/how-do-i-bind-xml-file-to-dropdownlist-using-xml-datasource) bcuz `author` and `year` are nodes not attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I get an error like 'DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSourceNodeDescriptor', does not contain an attribution like author.'

Comment: @KorayDurudogan - Yeah that is a limitation of XMLDataSource it doesn't work with elements rather it works with attributes.

Comment: @KorayDurudogan - Check my second update. You will not have to modify your XML. It's working fine for me.